# Flutter: Async task do not work as expected in "initState()"

Tags: android, ios, asynchronous, dart, flutter

I am trying to populate the `DropDownMenu` in my flutter app, using the data I get from a REST API. Below is how I get my data.

```
     class _CreateSellingAdvertisementState extends State<CreateSellingAdvertisement> {

      List<String> categoryList = List<String>();
      List<String> productList = List<String>();
      List<String> productUnitList = List<String>();

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();

        //Load category List
        DataFetch()
            .fetchCategoryList(
                AppNavigation.getAPIUrl() +
                    "productCategory/getAllProductCategories",
                ProductCategory)
            .then((onValue) {

              List<String> listString = new List<String>();

          for (int i = 0; i < onValue.length; i++) {
            listString.add(onValue[i].categoryName);
          }

          setState(() {
           categoryList = listString; 
          });
        });

print(categoryList);
...........................
    }
```

When I print the `categoryList` above, it is always `[]`. But I have used the same method using `FutureBuilder` and it works fine.

Below is `DataFetch().fetchCategoryList` method

```
 Future<List<ProductCategory>> fetchCategoryList(
      String url, Object obj) async {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate
    return parseCategoryDataList(response.body);
  }

  List<ProductCategory> parseCategoryDataList(String responseBody) {
    final parsed =
        convert.json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

    List<ProductCategory> list = parsed
        .map<ProductCategory>((json) => new ProductCategory.fromJson(json))
        .toList();
    return list;
  }
```

Below is my drop down list code

```
Widget _buildDropDown(List<String> list) {
    return new DropdownButton<String>(
      items: list.map((String value) {
        return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: new Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
      value: "A",
      isExpanded: true,
      onChanged: (_) {},
    );
  }
```

The dropdown list always throws the below exception

```
I/flutter (21217): The following assertion was thrown building CreateSellingAdvertisement(dirty, state:
I/flutter (21217): _CreateSellingAdvertisementState#1a80a):
I/flutter (21217): 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 560 pos 15: 'items == null ||
I/flutter (21217): items.isEmpty || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value ==
I/flutter (21217): value).length == 1': is not true.
I/flutter (21217): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter (21217): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter (21217): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter (21217):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter (21217): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (21217): #2      new DropdownButton 
I/flutter (21217): #3      _CreateSellingAdvertisementState._buildDropDown
I/flutter (21217): #4      _CreateSellingAdvertisementState.build
I/flutter (21217): #5      StatefulElement.build 
I/flutter (21217): #6      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
I/flutter (21217): #7      Element.rebuild 
I/flutter (21217): #8      BuildOwner.buildScope 
I/flutter (21217): #9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame 
I/flutter (21217): #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback 
I/flutter (21217): #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback 
I/flutter (21217): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame 
I/flutter (21217): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame 
I/flutter (21217): #17     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:209:10)
I/flutter (21217): #18     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:168:3)
I/flutter (21217): (elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and package dart:async)
```

Why is this?

Comment: can you try to print categoryList just after `setState` inside `.then` and check

Answer (score 0):

The `Future` method works inside `initState`, the issue here seems to be caused by the List not being updated as expected. The for loop is better placed inside `setState()` when an item is added to the List, and it's preferable to add the items to `categoryList` directly.

```dart
setState((){
  for (int i = 0; i < onValue.length; i++) {  
    categoryList.add(onValue[i].categoryName);  
  }
});
```

Calling `setState()` inside the for loop should also work similarly.

```dart
for (int i = 0; i < onValue.length; i++) {  
  setState(() {
    categoryList.add(onValue[i].categoryName);  
  }
}
```